# Could not find GPIO edge file on OrangePi Lite

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, gpio, wiringpi, orange-pi

Today when I started learning how to use the JavaScript "onoff" library and then ran into some problems with them, specifically.

First of all, I cannot use the names of the existing GPIOs and the names in the wPi, I can only use the BCM.

When I use the pins declared in BCM to blink the led, it works great. But when I use some other pins as buttons I get the error:

```
gpio: Warning: File not present: /sys/class/gpio/gpio110/edge
```

and it's clear that the edge folder isn't actually there. When I use:

```sh
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio110/value
```

for the pins that don't have an edge file, I get the error:

```
-bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

[OrangePiLite I/O](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHt9i.png)

[A problem I encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJP9V.png)

[Trying to use `echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio110/value`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEo31.png)

I tried manually copying the edge files from the existing files of other GPIO but that doesn't seem to be possible. Does anyone know how to fix it or can give me more information about them?

Comment: Try ` sudo echo {put pin number here} > /sys/class/gpio/export`

Comment: @Vinay I don't see any change in it

Comment: @Vinay: it won't work as redirection is done as the current user before the command runs

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got to use GPIO pins with out edge. It was a mistake when I tried to read its rising and falling edges. Just declare GPIO and use:

```js
button.readSync()
```

Here is my simple code:

```js
const Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
const button = new Gpio(71, 'in', {debounceTimeout:50});

const readbutton = _ => {

console.log(button.readSync());  
setTimeout(readbutton, 100);

};

readbutton();

process.on('SIGINT', _ => {
led.unexport();
button.unexport();

});
```

and in the npm onoff I found this here

[npm onoff image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBuvC.png)

Comment: Buttons usually are being serviced by `gpio-keys` driver with the respective excerpt in the Device Tree. Why do you need a custom non-standard code for that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, is that better than npm onoff? I just learned a little about linux as well as js, can you give me specific examples of that gpio-keys?

Comment: There are two possibilities on how you serve the hardware: 1) In-kernel driver (`gpio-keys`, or 2) user space driver (your custom code). The first one is much more preferable due to many reasons: performance, testing coverage, standardization and hece portability.

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add @USER to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)